# Javascript: Mapping values from one array to keys within a multidimational array

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to Javascript.
I am struggling with data wrangling. I would like to avoid loops.

I need to keep the higher levels of structure of "data_1", but insert an object in place of each of the key values of the form {name: "Key *n*", length: *int*}

The objects have of the following structures:

```
const data_1 = {
  Category1: ["Key A", "Key B", "Key C"],
  Category2: ["Key D", "Key E", "Key F"],
  Category3: ["Key G", "Key H"]
}

const data_2 = {
  "Key A": 100,
  "Key B": 200,
  "Key C": 300,
  "Key D": 400,
  "Key E": 400,
  "Key F": 300,
  "Key G": 200,
  "Key H": 100
}
```

The target structure should be:

```
result = {
  Category1: [{name:"Key A", length:100}, {name:"Key B", length:200}, {name: "Key C", length:300}],
  Category2: [{name:"Key D", length:400}, {name:"Key E", length:400}, {name: "Key F", length:300}],
  Category3: [{name:"Key G", length:200}, {name:"Key H", length:100}]
}
```

I suspect the way to tackle this is something akin to the following pseudo code. I am struggling to define an object as [name: key, length:data_2.key] .

```
let results = Object.fromEntries(data_1.map(key => [name: key, length:data_2.key]));
```

Any and all help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we grab the entries, we can map over the keys and get each of them like this. Then we can create an object from the transformed entries.

```js
const data_1 = {
  Category1: ["Key A", "Key B", "Key C"],
  Category2: ["Key D", "Key E", "Key F"],
  Category3: ["Key G", "Key H"]
};

const data_2 = {
  "Key A": 100,
  "Key B": 200,
  "Key C": 300,
  "Key D": 400,
  "Key E": 400,
  "Key F": 300,
  "Key G": 200,
  "Key H": 100
};

const data_3 = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data_1)
        .map(([cat, keys]) => [cat, keys.map((key) => ({ name: key, length: data_2[key] }))]
    )
);

console.log(data_3);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks again caTS :)

So the first conceptual bit I was missing was the Object.entries(data_1) to split up that structure.

So the idea is we first take the entries from each  of the categories (  "cat 1": [key1, ... key n] ) we then map over that specifying that for each of the cats and their respective keys we want an object, which is defined with the following  ({  name: key, length: data_2[key]  }) . 

makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @Skyehawk Yes that is correct. "cats" is short for categories :p

Answer (score 2):

- Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), get list of key-value pairs from `data_1`
- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over the above while updating the resulting object

  - In each iteration, add the new pair where the value is the list of objects having `name` and `length` generated using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). We use the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...acc`) to preserve existing accumulated pairs in every iteration.

```js
const 
  data_1 = { Category1: ["Key A", "Key B", "Key C"], Category2: ["Key D", "Key E", "Key F"], Category3: ["Key G", "Key H"] },
  data_2 = { 'Key A': 100, 'Key B': 200, 'Key C': 300, 'Key D': 400, 'Key E': 400, 'Key F': 300, 'Key G': 200, 'Key H': 100 };

const result = Object.entries(data_1).reduce((acc, [key, names]) => ({
  ...acc,
  [key]: names.map(name => ({ name, length: data_2[name] }))
}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Tricky syntax... OP might need to be told what the ...acc followed by a comma operator actually does. I for one am intrigued by the ...acc

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't mind a quick explanation. Tryin' to learn.   :)

Answer (score 2):

A reduce will do the trick and be quite readable too

```js
const result = Object.entries(data_1).reduce((acc, [key, vals]) => {
  acc[key] = vals.map(val => ({ name: val,length: data_2[val] }));
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const data_1 = {
  Category1: ["Key A", "Key B", "Key C"],
  Category2: ["Key D", "Key E", "Key F"],
  Category3: ["Key G", "Key H"]
}

const data_2 = {
  "Key A": 100,
  "Key B": 200,
  "Key C": 300,
  "Key D": 400,
  "Key E": 400,
  "Key F": 300,
  "Key G": 200,
  "Key H": 100
}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const result = {};

Object.keys(data_1).forEach((key) => {
  const item = data_1[key];
  result[key] = item.map((key) => {
    return { name: key, length: data_2[key] };
  });
});
```

Either way, seems a bit convoluted to use objects in that manner, when you could maybe use arrays for the data format.

Here's a snippet with a working example:

```js
const data_1 = {
  Category1: ['Key A', 'Key B', 'Key C'],
  Category2: ['Key D', 'Key E', 'Key F'],
  Category3: ['Key G', 'Key H'],
};

const data_2 = {
  'Key A': 100,
  'Key B': 200,
  'Key C': 300,
  'Key D': 400,
  'Key E': 400,
  'Key F': 300,
  'Key G': 200,
  'Key H': 100,
};

const result = {};

Object.keys(data_1).forEach((key) => {
  const item = data_1[key];
  result[key] = item.map((key) => {
    return { name: key, length: data_2[key] };
  });
});

console.log(result);
```